# Is there a way to add an order ID to the Square Reader SDK Checkout Flow?

Tags: react-native, square-connect, square

I come from a react web background and I'm familiar with the online payments api. Currently, I am using the react native quick start for the square reader SDK. The SDK uses:

`await startCheckoutAsync(checkoutParams)`

which is a function that handles payment through the mobile application without connecting to a backend (which is what I'm used to in Web application development). The checkout parameters look like this:

```
    // A checkout parameter is required for this checkout method
    const checkoutParams = {
      amountMoney: {
        amount: 100,
        currencyCode: 'USD', // optional, use authorized location's currency code by default
      },
      // Optional for all following configuration
      skipReceipt: false,
      collectSignature: true,
      allowSplitTender: false,
      delayCapture: false,
      note: 'Hello   World!',
      tipSettings: {
        showCustomTipField: true,
        showSeparateTipScreen: false,
        tipPercentages: [15, 20, 30],
      },
      additionalPaymentTypes: ['cash', 'manual_card_entry', 'other'],
    };
```

However my issue is that there is no way to associate an order with this checkout flow. 
According to the Square Reader documentation: 
https://github.com/square/react-native-square-reader-sdk/blob/master/docs/reference.md#checkoutparameter

checkout parameter does not take in an order id, or someway to map what is getting sold, unlike the online create payment api:
https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/payments-api/create-payment

which specifies an order id in the API call.

How do I properly handle associating an order Id to the react-native card reader sdk checkout flow

Answer (score 0):

At this time, there is no proper way to link an order to a ReaderSDK payment. ReaderSDK does not allow itemization currently, [per the docs](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/reader-sdk/what-it-does).

Comment: do you recommend an alternative?

Comment: @HarounAnsari did you ever come up with a solution to this? Working through a similar need now (2 years later) and this is still the case. Transactions which are used by the reader SDK are also deprecated now even though there are no options for using the new Payments.